# How to start a scanner at line X

Tags: java

I want to loop through the lines of an HTML document and print out the outputs.

Normally I'd do something like

```
URL url = new URL("http://google.com");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(url.openStream());

while(scanner.hasNext())
    System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
```

However, say I wanted to start printing out things at line 30 and onwards, rather than line 1. What would I do then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `scanner.nextLine` 30 times first, then start printing. For example:

```
// go through the first 30 lines without printing them...
for (int i = 0 ; i < 30 && scanner.hasNextLine() ; i++) {
    scanner.nextLine();
}

// and now print the remaining lines
while(scanner.hasNextLine())
    System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
```